# SEO friendly URL (Permalinks) not working for Wordpress on NGINX

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

We have wordpress installedin a subdirectory on our NGINX server. We want our blog URL to look something like www.example.com/blog. Individual blog posts urls should be like www.example.com/blog/post-name. For this when we go to setting->permalinks menu in wordpress and change it to Post Name from Default, it starts giving error. But it works just fine when we leave it default (www.example.com/blog/?p=123).
Blog directory is installed under html folder in nginx.
We've made following entry in nginx.conf file:

```
location /blog {

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

location ~ \.php$ {
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}
}
```

blog directory is installed at same level as the folder for our main site (example.com).
What are we doing wrong?

Comment: is it a 404 error? if so have you checked i think your Apache settings to allow the rewrite_module

Comment: We are using nginx and rewrite_module is built in. http://serverfault.com/questions/305780/how-to-enable-the-rewrite-feature-in-nginx-1-0-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
location /blog/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing - now wordpress is not able to pick any of our css/js/image files. Do we need to make any specific entry for that in location?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and I added this in my nginx conf to make it work for wordpress /index.php/permalink urls in nginx hhvm 3.21

Adding this for everyone's reference:

```
location / {

    ...
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php$fastcgi_script_name;


}
```

or

```
location / {

    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /index.php/$1 break;

}
```

Ensure you are using a fastcgi and not a server version (in server version you may get too many redirects due to rewrite)

- TESTED
- QA PASSED